# Thymeleaf Input Checkbox not binding in js file

Tags: javascript, spring, thymeleaf

I have a problem !  [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5FyzU.png) - this is my thymeleaf block with user roles , and this is my js file with ajax call post method [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rQn0R.png) , why roles dont binding to user when save it ?

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: You can take the [tour] and read [ask] for more guidance. You should try to provide a [mre] directly in the question (formatted text, data, error messages). You can [edit] your question to follow these guidelines.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.